# libGDX SpriteCache: transparency on images not displayed properly

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm developing a Tower Defense game using libGDX. I've just started and I am able to display the path, the "environment" and the enemies walking along the path.

I displayed the environment using a SpriteBatch-Object, like this:

```
public LevelController(Level level) {
    spriteBach = new SpriteBach();
    atlas =  new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("images/textures/textures.pack"));
}

public void setSize() {
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(this.cam.combined);
}

public void render() {
    spriteBatch.begin();
    drawTowerBases();
    spriteBatch.end();
}

private void drawTowerBases() {
    // for each tower base (=environment square)
    TextureRegion towerBaseTexture = atlas.findRegion("TowerBase");

    if(towerBaseTexture != null) {
        spriteBatch.draw(towerBaseTexture, x, y, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

This is working properly and the textures are displayed well: [Tower Defense using spriteBatch](http://img812.imageshack.us/img812/586/1ece.png)

Now, I was wondering if it is possible to cache the background. Because it stays the same,  there is no need to calculate it every time. I've found the SpriteCache through Google-Search. So I changed the code as follows:

```
public LevelController(Level Level) {
    spriteCache= new SpriteCache();

    atlas =  new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("images/textures/textures.pack"));

    spriteCache.beginCache();
    this.drawTowerBases();
    this.spriteCacheEnvironmentId = spriteCache.endCache();
}

public void setSize() {
    this.cam.update();
    spriteCache.setProjectionMatrix(this.cam.combined);
}

public void render() {
    spriteCache.begin();
    spriteCache.draw(this.spriteCacheEnvironmentId);
    spriteCache.end();
}

private void drawTowerBases() {
    // for each tower base (=environment square)
    TextureRegion towerBaseTexture = atlas.findRegion("TowerBase");

    if(towerBaseTexture != null) {
        spriteCache.add(towerBaseTexture, x, y, 1f, 1f);
    }
}
```

And now the game looks like this: [Tower Defense using spriteCache](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/3426/6owq.png)

For me it seems as if the transparency is not rendered properly. If I take images without transparency, everything works fine. Does anyone have an idea, why this happens and how I can fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [SpriteCache documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteCache.html):

> Note that SpriteCache does not manage blending. You will need to enable blending (Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);) and set the blend func as needed before or between calls to draw(int).

I guess there is not much more to say.

Comment: Thank you. I get it to work with calling this two lines before spriteCache.begin(): Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

Comment: I'm a little bit confused about SpriteCache. It is not stated clearly in the SpriteCache doc but it seems that SpriteCache is sort of a 'SNAPSHOT OF WHAT YOU JUST RENDERED' that gets stored in GPU memory. You can get this snapshot with its ID and put it on screen without sending everything once again. Is that correct? That would also mean you can render the snapshot anywhere on the screen - move it, right? The doc is a little bit puzzling with the 'geometry that does not change'.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your question is. Yes, you should be able to render the cache "anywhere" by manipulating its projection matrix.

Comment: While rendering with SpriteCache you create a shapshot of what you render and store it under an ID in GPU. You can recall it later with this ID. By manipulating SpriteCache projection matix you can show this snapshot anywhere you want. Is all me reasoning right? :)

Comment: I think so, why don't you just try it?